# Can an idea "make common sense"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Can I use the phrase common sense like that?

The United Kingdom can reverse #Brexit...if it wants to. The statement of the Court of Justice of the EU makes common sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really.

We typically say, "it makes sense" or "it is common sense."

The only way "sense" is commonly modified in the phrase "it makes sense" is in degree:

It makes a lot of sense
It doesn't make much sense